# disable text box from within php code

Tags: php, javascript

I'm looking to disable a textbox from within my php code. e.g.:

```
if($ps=='33' || $ps=='40' || $ps=='42' || $ps=='43')
{
$loc="$ps"."LIFT";

     //disable textbox here how do I invoke some javascript??//
     document.getElementById('txtLocation').disabled='disabled';    

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($ps=='33' || $ps=='40' || $ps=='42' || $ps=='43')
{
$loc="$ps"."LIFT";

     //disable textbox here how do I invoke some javascript??//
?><script>
     document.getElementById('txtLocation').disabled='disabled';    
</script><?php

}
```

Comment: Cheers. Thought so.. type error didn't get it working for me, d'oh.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way as I'm guessing your textbox is created after this code. Try this

```
$disabled="";
if($ps=='33' || $ps=='40' || $ps=='42' || $ps=='43')
{
    $loc="$ps"."LIFT";
    $disabled = "disabled";
}
```

Then where your textbox is written have this

```
<input type="text" disabled="<?php echo $disabled; ?>" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you will do all your pre-processing before rendering, and create the textbox as disabled already.

Alternatively, you can add an instruction to to some javascript initialization block you already have.

Finally, you can always output a script block, something along the lines of:

```
echo "<script language='JavaScript'>document.getElementById('txtLocation').disabled='disabled';<script>";
```

but... this is ugly.